# need to store the data in an array inside localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

i have made a small sumon math game where i have created 9 listitems with diffrent numbers on each listitem and every time value changes as the pages reload(random values come evreytime).

User has to click on the listitems to achieve the goal e.g suppose achieving target is 7 so user will click on 5 and 2 or watever to achieve 7.

Now what i want to do is suppose when i achieved the goal i want to save it in my local storage and next time when user restarts it and achieves a new values that too i want to store in local storage so what my point is to store data in an array format inside localstorage every time user achieves the goal.

Here is data_stack array which adds up the value and stores it into current value so i want to push this currentval everytime to an array.Please help me here

```
var currentval =  eval(data_stack.join('+'));
console.log(currentval);
```

Answer (score 1):

The key/value local storage (aka [Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)) only accepts strings. However, you can JSON encode your array and store the JSON, so when you retrieve it just decode it back to an array.

Storing the array as JSON:

```
// data_stack is an array
// store as JSON
localStorage.setItem('data_stack', JSON.stringify(data_stack));
```

Retrieving the JSON and decoding it:

```
var raw = localStorage.getItem('data_stack');
if(raw !== null) {
    var data_stack = JSON.parse(raw);
    // now you can push to data_stack or whatever
    data_stack.push('xyz');
}
```

Comment: hey MrCode thanks man but i need to store the result that is the addition of numbers inside an array,so everytime i have to push the result to an array, by this we are just pushing the data_stack array to some other array or var

Comment: I see what you're saying but it doesn't matter what array you want to persist in local storage, the same principle applies of JSON encoding it for storage, then JSON decoding it back to an array that you can manipulate as required, then store back to local storage.

Comment: @MrCode's solution looks good. But if you are trying to append consider keeping a constant key to indes into a key for each score. Then you can encode each independently..